# Android Studio in mac

Tags: mac, android, android-studio

I faced a problem in Android studio. Please do recommend me any good idea to solve this problem.I have downloaded the latest android studio version and it is showing me this error. It tells “  Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network) “
I do have fast Internet connection. but it doesnot download dependencies.
Neither it build gradle.
I tried it more than 1000 times but i can’t solve it.
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4' . This is my dependency version.
I tried downloading every gradle file but also cant solve it. 
If you guys have its any solution. Please do help me. It is urgent.

Iam using android-studio-3.1,4.0 version in macbook 10.8.5 
Lower than this android studio version works but later than this doesnot works.

If you guys have any idea,please do help me.Instead I will also help you next time.
Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd7Zy.png)

Comment: Have you tried to clean Gradle cache?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue on windows.
I tried different approaches like downloading that gradle version with a download manager and extracting it then set the android studio gradle folder on that path from settings.

What I would suggest for you is - use same gradle version on your project and also try to download it yourself and put the zip file in a similar folder, proceeded, highlighted in the below picture. I dont know what the mac equivalent folder path will be but I hope you will be able to find that by digging inside with finder. `C:\Users\...\.gradle\wrapper\dists`
[image]

when downloading the same file next time it will just extract that and proceed to the rest.

Let me know if this helps.